# Why print("\5") output a new line in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between `print("\n")` and `print("\5")`?

I tried below in a python shell.

Why does print("\5") output a new line:

```
>>> print("\n")


>>> print("\5")

>>>
```

But when I tried:

> > > print("\4")
> > >
> > > print("\6")
> > >
> > > It's printing some binary data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: My question is not to know about the newline print in python. It's related to what is difference between i) print("\n") ii) print("\5") iii) print("\4")
Only print("\5") gives a newline but apart from 5 whatever we use inside a print with "\" like "\4", "\6" will give binary output.
I hope this gives the reason why its not a duplicate one. @AlexYu

Comment: Short answer (in my opinion): because `print` always outputs newline not matter what symbols you are `print`ing. But I can agree that your question is not full duplicate - it was kind of stretch from me

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you use `print` in python, it puts a newline at the end.  The thing you should pay attention to is how many newlines are in the output.

`"\5"` is just a character (it's the control characters ENQ in ASCII; while it is technically non-printable, my terminal renders it as ♣); printing it outputs whatever your terminal decides to use to render it followed by a newline.  `print("")` will output a newline.  `print("\n")` by contrast will output two newlines.

If your terminal can't/won't render `\5` (it is a non-printable character after all), `print("\5")` will be the same as `print("")`.

Comment: "The clubs symbol"…?

Comment: @deceze That's just what my terminal renders it as